# How to interactively authenticate to Azure via SDK?

Tags: azure, f#, f#-interactive

I found this Gist: [azure-service-bus-in-fsharp-with-fluent-api.fs](https://gist.github.com/Youenn-Bouglouan/7ba237e6a4663d9b7575124cbd8cb3ac) which originally appeared to be useful but I believe it is already dated and that one should use now `DefaultAzureCredential`.

I use Visual Studio Code but want to authenticate interactively.

I created a service principal, got its client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, and also the subscription_id.

My code so far is:

```
#r "nuget: Azure.Identity"
open Azure.Identity

let spDefaultAzCredentialOptions = 
    DefaultAzureCredentialOptions (
        ManagedIdentityClientId = Guid.NewGuid ()
)
let servicePrincipal = DefaultAzureCredential spDefaultAzCredentialOptions
```

In this particular instance, I get the error:

```
Binding session to 'C:/Users/{user}/.nuget/packages/azure.identity/1.6.1/lib/netstandard2.0/Azure.Identity.dll'...
Binding session to 'C:/Users/{user}/.nuget/packages/azure.core/1.23.0/lib/net5.0/Azure.Core.dll'...
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Azure.Core.ClientOptions..ctor(Azure.Core.DiagnosticsOptions)'.
   at Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions..ctor()
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredentialOptions..ctor()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0033>.$FSI_0033.main@() in C:\Users\{user \ path}\PowerShell\stdin:line 91
Stopped due to error
```

However, in Microsoft's documentation [DefaultAzureCredentialOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredentialoptions?view=azure-dotnet) I can find the property -- but also see that the constructor is empty.

Generally, how can I authenticate interactive to Azure using F#?

Comment: There's a typo in your code. The name of the property is `ManagedIdentityClientId` and not `ManagedIdentityClientID` (notice uppercase "D" at the last).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the extensive documentation of `DefaultAzureCredential` it took me a bit to understand how I could use it in my case. The first authentication method of it is to use environment variables.
So, I first created a record -- not necessary but for my clarity -- and then created the new variables.

```
type ServicePrincipalCredentials = {
    ClientId: Guid
    ClientSecret: string
    TenantId: Guid 
}

let credentials = {
    ClientId = Guid.Parse "appId"
    ClientSecret = "Service Principal Password"
    TenantId = Guid.Parse "tenant" 
}

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", credentials.ClientId.ToString())
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", credentials.ClientSecret)
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("AZURE_TENANT_ID", credentials.TenantId.ToString())
```

Afterwards, the `DefaultAzureCredential` should work. I used it successfully with the resource manager to create an `ArmClient`.

```
#r "nuget: Azure.ResourceManager.Resources, 1.3.0"
open Azure.ResourceManager
open Azure.ResourceManager.Resources

let client = Azure.ResourceManager.ArmClient(DefaultAzureCredential())
```